# Semi dense point tracking

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, emgucv, opticalflow

I'm trying to implement [this](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~garrigues/video_extruder.html) semi dense point tracking using Emgu cv. Can anyone help me to find the algorithms implemented in this https://github.com/matt-42/cuimg.git c++ package. There are many header and cpp files i cannot figure out the relevant methods used. Or can someone guide me to compile the sample tracking file given inside c++ project using visual studio 2010 . it's in here https://github.com/matt-42/cuimg/tree/master/samples/tracking

I'm trying to convert this c++ project because Optical flow in Emgu Cv doesn't give satisfying result when tracking motion a moving camera. I found above c++ project which tracks point in a scene very accurately.But I'm not very good at c++. Can someone guide me how to start. Your help is really appreciated.